# preprocess_input in keras increase the size of train drastically

Tags: keras, image-preprocessing

Before training with a resnet50 model, I preprocessed my input using:

```
img = image.load_img(os.path.join(TRAIN, img), target_size=[224, 224])
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = preprocess_input(img)
```

and save a numpy array of images.
I found out that without `preprocess_input`, the size of the array is 1.5G, with preprocess_input, the size is 7G.
Is that a normal behavior? Or am I missing something?
Why does `Zero-center by mean pixel` drastically increase the input size?

This is how `zero center by mean pixel` is defined in keras

`x = x[..., ::-1]
x[..., 0] -= 103.939
x[..., 1] -= 116.779
x[..., 2] -= 123.68`

Comment: How is `preprocess_input` defined? What do you mean by `Zero-center by mean pixel`?

Comment: If you refer to keras implementation of ```preprocess_input``` you can see these lines of code
```x[..., 0] -= 103.939
        x[..., 1] -= 116.779
        x[..., 2] -= 123.68```.

Comment: I finally decided to use a generator. so i don't need to worry again about the size of the data. only a chunk of data was preprocessed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because pixel values were of the type 'uint8', and now they are of type 'float'.
So now you have an image, which is a 'float' array, which is larger than a 'uint8' array.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from keras implementation of `preprocess_input`
The images are normalized by subtracting the dataset's image mean which seems to be  constants obtained from imagenet. Here the code

```
def _preprocess_numpy_input(x, data_format, mode):
if mode == 'tf':
    x /= 127.5
    x -= 1.
    return x

if data_format == 'channels_first':
    if x.ndim == 3:
        # 'RGB'->'BGR'
        x = x[::-1, ...]
        # Zero-center by mean pixel
        x[0, :, :] -= 103.939
        x[1, :, :] -= 116.779
        x[2, :, :] -= 123.68
    else:
        x = x[:, ::-1, ...]
        x[:, 0, :, :] -= 103.939
        x[:, 1, :, :] -= 116.779
        x[:, 2, :, :] -= 123.68
else:
    # 'RGB'->'BGR'
    x = x[..., ::-1]
    # Zero-center by mean pixel
    x[..., 0] -= 103.939
    x[..., 1] -= 116.779
    x[..., 2] -= 123.68
return x
```

I don't undersstant why using this piece of code increased the size of my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

According to TensorFlow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input)
argument is:
A floating point numpy.array or a tf.Tensor, 3D or 4D with 3 color channels, with values in the range [0, 255].
and the function returns
Returns:
Preprocessed numpy.array or a tf.Tensor with type float32.

I have a feeling that the integers uses different amount of memory.